# Read file from aws s3 bucket using node fs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fs

I am attempting to read a file that is in a aws s3 bucket using

```
fs.readFile(file, function (err, contents) {
  var myLines = contents.Body.toString().split('\n')
})
```

I've been able to download and upload a file using the node aws-sdk, but I am at a loss as to how to simply read it and parse the contents.

Here is an example of how I am reading the file from s3:

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var params = {Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: 'myKey.csv'}
var s3file = s3.getObject(params)
```

Comment: contents.Body.toString() instead of contents.Body

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You have a couple options. You can include a callback as a second argument, which will be invoked with any error message and the object. This [example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property) is straight from the AWS documentation:

```
s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Alternatively, you can convert the output to a stream. There's also an [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html#createReadStream-property) in the AWS documentation:

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});
var params = {Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: 'myImageFile.jpg'};
var file = require('fs').createWriteStream('/path/to/file.jpg');
s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(file);
```

Comment: What if I also wish to use a Promise for better overall async handling?

Comment: @verveguy You can use the following: `new Promise((resolve, reject) => {s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().on('end', () => { return resolve(); }).on('error', (error) => { return reject(error); }).pipe(file)});`

Comment: @verveguy Depending on which version of node you are running, the aws-sdk version > 2.3.0, will use native promises. You can also explicitly configure which promise library you would like to use. 

`if (typeof Promise === 'undefined') {
    console.log("Using Bluebird for Promises");
    AWS.config.setPromisesDependency(require('bluebird'));
}`

Comment: How we can know if pipe() has been ended so that we can do another task on the file after writing it locally...?

Comment: What if the json file you want to read is compressed. Will createReadStream().pipe(file); deal with that issue?

Answer (score 62):

This will do it:

```
new AWS.S3().getObject({ Bucket: this.awsBucketName, Key: keyName }, function(err, data)
{
    if (!err)
        console.log(data.Body.toString());
});
```

Comment: For me, this should be the selected answer. Short and sweet!

Answer (score 29):

Since you seem to want to process an S3 text file line-by-line.  Here is a Node version that uses the standard readline module and AWS' createReadStream()

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: s3.getObject(params).createReadStream()
});

rl.on('line', function(line) {
    console.log(line);
})
.on('close', function() {
});
```

Comment: I think the `end` event is called `close` instead. https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_close

Comment: If you want to handle gzipped source files, you can use `s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(zlib.createGunzip())` as InputStream as well...

Answer (score 17):

If you are looking to avoid the callbacks you can take advantage of the sdk .promise() function like this:

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const params = {Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: 'myKey.csv'}
const response = await s3.getObject(params).promise() // await the promise
const fileContent = response.Body.toString('utf-8'); // can also do 'base64' here if desired
```

I'm sure the other ways mentioned here have their advantages but this works great for me. Sourced from this thread (see the last response from AWS): https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=116788

Comment: What is getObjectResult in the last line?

Comment: Gold! But indeed, line 4 should be ```const fileContent = response.Body.toString('utf-8');```.

Comment: what about if the json file that you want to read from is compressed?

Answer (score 11):

here is the example which i used to retrive and parse json data from s3.

```
    var params = {Bucket: BUCKET_NAME, Key: KEY_NAME};
    new AWS.S3().getObject(params, function(err, json_data)
    {
      if (!err) {
        var json = JSON.parse(new Buffer(json_data.Body).toString("utf8"));

       // PROCESS JSON DATA
           ......
     }
   });
```

Comment: i think you need to write down how to process the json data as well

Comment: after calling JSON.parse in line 5, you'll have a regular js object. If your json is `"{"name": "John", "id": 1}"`
on line 8 you can just call `json.name`

Answer (score 9):

I couldn't figure why yet, but the `createReadStream`/`pipe` approach didn't work for me. I was trying to download a large CSV file (300MB+) and I got duplicated lines. It seemed a random issue. The final file size varied in each attempt to download it.

I ended up using another way, based on [AWS JS SDK examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-examples.html#Amazon_S3__Streaming_Objects_to_Files_on_Disk__getObject_):

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var params = {Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: 'myImageFile.jpg'};
var file = require('fs').createWriteStream('/path/to/file.jpg');

s3.getObject(params).
    on('httpData', function(chunk) { file.write(chunk); }).
    on('httpDone', function() { file.end(); }).
    send();
```

This way, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 9):

I prefer **`Buffer.from(data.Body).toString('utf8')`**. It supports encoding parameters. With other AWS services (ex. Kinesis Streams) someone may want to replace `'utf8'` encoding with `'base64'`.

```
new AWS.S3().getObject(
  { Bucket: this.awsBucketName, Key: keyName }, 
  function(err, data) {
    if (!err) {
      const body = Buffer.from(data.Body).toString('utf8');
      console.log(body);
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 7):

I had exactly the same issue when downloading from S3 very large files.

The example solution from AWS docs just does not work:

```
var file = fs.createWriteStream(options.filePath);
        file.on('close', function(){
            if(self.logger) self.logger.info("S3Dataset file download saved to %s", options.filePath );
            return callback(null,done);
        });
        s3.getObject({ Key:  documentKey }).createReadStream().on('error', function(err) {
            if(self.logger) self.logger.error("S3Dataset download error key:%s error:%@", options.fileName, error);
            return callback(error);
        }).pipe(file);
```

While this solution will work:

```
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(options.filePath);
    s3.getObject({ Bucket: this._options.s3.Bucket, Key: documentKey })
    .on('error', function(err) {
        if(self.logger) self.logger.error("S3Dataset download error key:%s error:%@", options.fileName, error);
        return callback(error);
    })
    .on('httpData', function(chunk) { file.write(chunk); })
    .on('httpDone', function() { 
        file.end(); 
        if(self.logger) self.logger.info("S3Dataset file download saved to %s", options.filePath );
        return callback(null,done);
    })
    .send();
```

The `createReadStream` attempt just does not fire the `end`, `close` or `error` callback for some reason. See [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1523) about this.

I'm using that solution also for writing down archives to gzip, since the first one (AWS example) does not work in this case either:

```
        var gunzip = zlib.createGunzip();
        var file = fs.createWriteStream( options.filePath );

        s3.getObject({ Bucket: this._options.s3.Bucket, Key: documentKey })
        .on('error', function (error) {
            if(self.logger) self.logger.error("%@",error);
            return callback(error);
        })
        .on('httpData', function (chunk) {
            file.write(chunk);
        })
        .on('httpDone', function () {

            file.end();

            if(self.logger) self.logger.info("downloadArchive downloaded %s", options.filePath);

            fs.createReadStream( options.filePath )
            .on('error', (error) => {
                return callback(error);
            })
            .on('end', () => {
                if(self.logger) self.logger.info("downloadArchive unarchived %s", options.fileDest);
                return callback(null, options.fileDest);
            })
            .pipe(gunzip)
            .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(options.fileDest))
        })
        .send();
```

Answer (score 7):

With the new version of sdk, the accepted answer does not work - it does not wait for the object to be downloaded. The following code snippet will help with the new version:

```
// dependencies

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

// get reference to S3 client

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

var bucket = "TestBucket"

var key = "TestKey"

   try {

      const params = {
            Bucket: Bucket,
            Key: Key
        };

       var theObject = await s3.getObject(params).promise();

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
    }  
}
```

Comment: var theObject = await s3.getObject(params).promise() This is the correct way. Thanks

Comment: "errorType": "TypeError",
  "errorMessage": "s3.getObject(...).promise is not a function",

sdk v3, node20

Answer (score 5):

If you want to save memory and want to obtain each row as a json object, then you can use [`fast-csv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-csv) to create readstream and can read each row as a json object as follows:

```
const csv = require('fast-csv');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const credentials = new AWS.Credentials("ACCESSKEY", "SECRETEKEY", "SESSIONTOKEN");
AWS.config.update({
    credentials: credentials, // credentials required for local execution
    region: 'your_region'
});
const dynamoS3Bucket = new AWS.S3();
const stream = dynamoS3Bucket.getObject({ Bucket: 'your_bucket', Key: 'example.csv' }).createReadStream();

var parser = csv.fromStream(stream, { headers: true }).on("data", function (data) {
    parser.pause();  //can pause reading using this at a particular row
    parser.resume(); // to continue reading
    console.log(data);
}).on("end", function () {
    console.log('process finished');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var fileStream = fs.createWriteStream('/path/to/file.jpg');
var s3Stream = s3.getObject({Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: 'myImageFile.jpg'}).createReadStream();

// Listen for errors returned by the service
s3Stream.on('error', function(err) {
    // NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist
    console.error(err);
});

s3Stream.pipe(fileStream).on('error', function(err) {
    // capture any errors that occur when writing data to the file
    console.error('File Stream:', err);
}).on('close', function() {
    console.log('Done.');
});
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/requests-using-stream-objects.html