# Read content of txt file from s3 bucket with Node

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I would like to read the content of a .txt file stored within an s3 bucket.

I tried :

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});
var params = {Bucket: 'My-Bucket', Key: 'MyFile.txt'};
var s3file = s3.getObject(params)
```

But the s3file object that i get does not contain the content of the file.

Do you have an idea on what to do ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read file from aws s3 bucket using node fs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27299139/read-file-from-aws-s3-bucket-using-node-fs)

Answer (score 1):

Agree with zishone and here is the code with exception handling:

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});
var params = {Bucket: 'My-Bucket', Key: 'MyFile.txt'};

s3.getObject(params , function (err, data) {

    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(data.Body.toString());
    }

})
```

Comment: Thank you, it does not raise an error but it does not print someting in the console. Why ? How to get the result ?

Comment: This thing works perfectly for me. Post your lambda and the role you are using, and the bucket policy if you have.  Here is my lmbda
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {  


    var s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'}); var params = {Bucket: 'bucket-name', Key: 'test.txt'};

    s3.getObject(params , function (err, data) {

    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("TEXT FROM FILE: " + data.Body.toString());
    }
    })
};

Comment: I use a lambda full acces role, with the code you sent. It does not print anything in the console.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property) the contents of your file will be in the `Body` field of the result and it will be a `Buffer`.

And another problem there is that `s3.getObject(` should have a callback.

```
s3.getObject(params, (err, s3file) => {
    const text = s3file.Body.toString();
})
```

Comment: Thx, however, how to return the content in a str variable ? (I am new to Node ..)