# How can I read the contents of an item in an S3 bucket using the javascript aws-sdk version 3?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

I'm trying to fetch the contents of a file in an s3 bucket, so I can parse it as JSON and do stuff with it. I'm using the aws js sdk version 3, with typescript. The code snippet at https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javascriptv3/example_code/s3/actions/get-object.js#L22 doesn't work: NodeJS complains that `transformToString` isn't a function on the item:

```
const response = await client.send(
  new GetObjectCommand({ Bucket: "the-bucket-name", Key: "the-file.json" })
);
    
const str = await (response.Body as any).transformToString();
```

```
TypeError: response.Body.transformToString is not a function
```

I believe the bucket and key are correct; if I change them, I get a different error:

```
AccessDenied: Access Denied
```

How can I get the contents of the item into a string so I can parse it as JSON? I'm using the following package versions:

```
"@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.35.0",
"@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager": "^3.35.0",
"@aws-sdk/client-sts": "^3.35.0",
"@aws-sdk/credential-provider-node": "^3.35.0",
"@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner": "^3.35.0",
```

Comment: Doesn't this question help you?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27299139/read-file-from-aws-s3-bucket-using-node-fs

Comment: @ArpitJain I don't think so. That's using an old version of the AWS Javascript SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, try this:

```js
const str = await response.Body.transformToString();
```